# Could not find the correct Provider<> above this VisitSchedulesScreen Widget

Tags: flutter, state-management

i am trying to add provider state management to my flutter application,
i put the provider in the root of my application as below :

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: VisitSchedules())
        ],
        child: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
```

in the first widget under the (material app widget) the state management is working fine, but when routing to new screen i am facing an error in using the state management.
this is my new screen code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sim_distribution/screens/VisitDetailScreen.dart';

import '../data/visit_schedules.dart';

class VisitSchedulesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var visitSchedules = Provider.of<VisitSchedules>(context, listen: true).getPendingVisitCount();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Visit Schedules'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: visitSchedules,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final schedule = visitSchedules;
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => VisitDetailScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('Date: ${}'),
              subtitle: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('Customer: ${schedule}'),
                  Text('Location: ${schedule}'),
                ],
              ),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Add navigation or action when the representative taps on a schedule
                  // For example, navigate to a visit details screen
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the error that appears when ever i go to that page :

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<VisitSchedules> above this VisitSchedulesScreen Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that VisitSchedulesScreen is under your MultiProvider/Provider<VisitSchedules>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  

  consider using `builder` like so:

 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Even in the official [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) it says that shouldn't use Provider.value to create your object:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
  value: MyModel(),
  child: ...
)
```

Instead, go for the recommended way to declare your providers:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
    useMaterial3: true,
  ),
  home: MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => VisitSchedules()) // Correction here
    ],
    child: HomeScreen(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: i did that also, still the same error

Comment: Have you made a clean run after this?

Comment: yes dear for sure